# android iterate through objects on xml and find the type

Tags: java, android, xml, iteration

Is there a way to iterate through the objects on a form and find all the types.  In VBNet you would do something like:

```
For each control on form
  print typename(control)
```

What I mean by a form is the UI that the user can see, I guess that is the Context?  If I have an XML that say has 2 buttons and a textview, is there a way from the java code to see what all of the object are that has been loaded from the XML.

I am trying to make a generic class that I can use on all UI classes that will look through every object and if its a button then change the colors on that button.

Alternately I could do this manually for every UI and object.

Comment: If you are iterating through xml files (and not the resources) then I think it's more of a java question (add java tag)

Comment: Can you be be more specific about what you mean by "form" in the context of an Android app?

Comment: I am not sure how to add things so I edited my question above.

Answer (score 0):

a normal "java for" :

```
for( Control c : ArrayList<Control> controlList){
    System.out.println(c.getTypeName();
}
```

hope it helps.

Comment: I am not sure how to add things so I edited my question above. I pasted this code into a test app and Eclipse doesnt know what a Control is.  Sorry I confused this issue not explaining well.  please see original question again